# React component not rerendering based on props change

Tags: reactjs

I have a prop classifiers array in my react component which changes when a file is uploaded via a form. I have to populate the classifiers field in my form based on the value of the classifier array. I am calling this.render() when the classifiers array is changed, but the list is not being populated.

Constructor:

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this.classifiers = [];
}
```

Render method:

```
render() {
    if(this.classifiers.length!==0){
        return(
           <form>
           </form>
        )
    }
    else{
        return(
            <form>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

Assume that the form component is written correctly. When I put some console logs into the if and the else of render, they work fine but the component is not rerendered with the new classifiers.

Comment: add code where you are calling this.render()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a prop classifiers array in my react component which changes
>   when a file is uploaded via a form.

classifier is not related to prop it is a class variable

> I have to populate the classifiers field in my form based on the value
>   of the classifier array.

When in a component you are having something that changes or varies from time to time please use state for that

```
this.state = {
    classifier: []
}
```

> I am calling this.render()

```
render()
```

it is meant to be called by react not explicitly by user. Do not interrupt the flow.

I suppose you can change classifier very well.
If not you can change it as

```
const updateClassifier = (items= []) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        return {
            classifier: [...prevState.classifier, ...items]
        }
    })

}
```

For rendering the form

```
const renderMyForm = () => {
    if(this.state.classifier.length !== 0){
        return (<form></form>);
    } else {
        return (<form></form>);
    }

}

render() {
    { renderMyForm ()}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The component is not updated by props but state... change state isteed of props...

```
this.setState({ whateverHere })
```

Comment: Accepted the other answer because it was quite elaborate and so easy to implement for a beginner like myself. Thank you for an answer nonetheless.